# ModelState with entities relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, n-tier-architecture

I am trying to make an a form for booking with client-side validation and backside validation. The client-side validation is successful and works properly. But there's a problem in server-side validation. This is from the `Booking` entity which has a one-to-one relationship with a customer:

```
//Relationship

[ForeignKey("Customer")]
public int customerID { get; set; }

public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

I send the `customerID` from the booking form

```
<input asp-for="Booking.customerID" value="1" hidden/>
```

but when I submit the form, the `modelState` will be false, and when I look for the reason, it become for the relationship

```
{[Booking.Customer, SubKey={Customer}, Key=Booking.Customer, ValidationState=Invalid]}
```

I am working with n-tier architecture in ASP.NET, and I have generic repository and interface.

What is the problem?

Comment: I assume you mean `<input type="hidden"...` not `<input hidden...`. You shouldn't edit your data model. The navigations in your data model should be nullable, so you can query and edit tables separately.

Answer (score 0):

If the app was built with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`, a missing value for  Customer property in a JSON or form post results in a validation error.

To avoid the modelState will be false, use of the `?` suffix to declare a nullable reference type  to allow null or missing values to be specified for the Customer property. Try to add `?` like:

```
public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
```

Comment: but the value of customer id shouldn't be a null value, or there is no related between the customer and customerID

Comment: i make it to accept null, but still the problem 
welcome.

Comment: @MohammedAlabri   "but still the problem welcome " What's problem ?